# unixODBC and DB2 ODBC connection issue on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, db2, odbc, unixodbc

I went through the tutorial on unixODBC.org website for DB2 connections and I can't successfully get the connection to succeed with isql. Think I’m getting stuck on the configuration of odbc.ini  vs  odbcinst.ini and  vs  db2cli.ini

I installed the iAccess drivers version 10.5 fix pack 6

```
ODBC.ini
[mustship]
Description=Connection to AS400
Driver=DB2
Host=10.220.1.10
Port=446
Username=common
Password=common

ODBCINST.ini
[DB2]
Description=DB2 Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so
FileUsage=1
DontDLClose=1

DB2CLI.ini
[mustship]
Database=matt
```

Error
[08001][unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1013N The database alias name or database name “MUSTSHIP” could not be found. SQLSTATE=42705

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

I am trying to connect to the library “matt” on my DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue, I found this great post explaining the process in more detail. This resolved it for me:

http://fractio.nl/2007/10/26/setting-up-unixodbc-with-a-remote-db2/